# dotted underline in richtextblock

Tags: xamarin, uwp, richtextblock

In Xamarin.UWP, I have created a custom renderer for label using richtextblock.  Within the richtextblock, I have used hyperlink to enter text with the ability to click on it.  Can I change the underline from straight to dotted?

Comment: Hi, You can set the appearance of the underline through UnderLineStyle, but currently only `None` and `Single` can be set, you may not be able to directly set the underline to the dotted line.

Comment: Is there a way to use UnderlineType Enum from Windows.Ui.Text? [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.underlinetype

Comment: In `RichTextBlock`, there is no implementation of `UnderlineType`, which lacks the necessary text document model. You can use `Border` and `TextBlock` to write a **UserControl** and add this Control to **InlineUIContainer**.